# Fortran double do cycles

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have two different arrays like this:

```
i=[98,99,100]
j=[25,69,30]
```

I would like to rotate through this value with a double do cycles but using the same component index during each iteration.

So for example first 98-25 then 99-69 and finally 100-30.
Then each of this combinations should be written in different files.

Thanks for any suggestions,

Best.

Comment: Why do you need a double do loop if you only want a single index? Isn't a single loop sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
do ix = 1,3
    do jx = i(ix),j(ix),-1
    ... stuff
    end do
end do
```

If that's not what you want, it's because you've not explained what you do want more clearly.